# How to create "Bug Category" on "Bug Work Item" using TFS 2013, that i faced error on "Reference Field Name" once I tried

Tags: tfs

when I try to add new field on Bug work item using TFS 2013, I faced issue that the reference name is not defined.

please support how can I create new field on work item, that the field as follows:

**Field Name:** Bug Category.

**Type:** String.

The the fields which I tried to create as follows:

```
  <FIELD name="Category" refname="System.Category" type="String" reportable="dimension">
         <ALLOWEDVALUES>
            <LISTITEM value="Bug" />
            <LISTITEM value="Enhanement" />
         </ALLOWEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no system field with the name `System.Category`. because is your custom field you need to give a name without `System`, for example:

```
Custom.Category
```

So just change the `refname="System.Category"` to `refname="Custom.Category"`.